# Abrir teclado numérico automaticamente

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic, teclado

Tenho uma página com um input numérico com autofocus:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Informe" ng-model='leitura.leituraatual' required="true" autofocus="true">
```

O problema é que o teclado aparece no modo Texto ao invés de modo numérico. Só aparece o teclado numérico se clico no input manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Achei!

Usei o plugin [cordova-android-focus-plugin](https://github.com/46cl/cordova-android-focus-plugin/)

```
<input id="txtLeituraAtual" type="number" >
```

JS:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){ 
    var txt=$window.document.getElementById("txtLeituraAtual");
    cordova.plugins.Focus.focus(txt);
});
```

Agora o input recebe o foco e abre o teclado numérico corretamente!

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a tag abaixo no arquivo `config.xml`

```xml
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

E então, no controller, chame o método `focus()` do input logo após tudo estar pronto.

```js
 $scope.init = function() {
     INPUT_AQUI.focus();
 }

 ...

 $scope.init();
```

Comment: Fiz assim: ```$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){ $window.document.getElementById("txtLeituraAtual").focus(); });```. Agora o input até recebe o foco mas o teclado não abre.

Comment: Se adiciono `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();` após o `focus()` o teclado abre, mas no modo texto. Eu queria que abrisse no modo numérico.

Comment: Tente mudar o `type` do input para `tel`, para testar.